# Varias condiciones dentro de un mismo if php

Tags: php, if

Necesito crear un if con varias condiciones hay muchos ejemplos en el foro pero no doy con ninguno que me sirva.
necesito que el if compruebe dos condiciones la primera verificando si el `$user_id` es igual al `auth()->user()->id)` si esta no coincidiera probara la segunda opción que seria verificar si $privacidad es null además de point mayor de 100 espero haberme explicado bien.

**Esto es lo que intento hacer** pero es correcto este sintaxis? "es solo un mal ejemplo para que me entendáis mejor"

```
@if( ( $user_id == auth()->user->id ) or ( $private = null and point >=100 )  )
```

Comment: Es que necesito que se cumpla 1 o si no las otras 2, no solo las 2

Comment: Listo perdonen mi mala explicación..

Comment: yo lo dejaría así: `
@if( $user_id == auth()->user->id or $private == null and point >=100  )` los detalles, quite los parentésis de mas y además de eso en: `$private = null` estas asignando que la variable $private valga null, en todo caso si quieres saber si la variable `$private` es igual a `null` debes usar doble símbolo de igual `==`

Comment: Perfecto shadow muchas gracias

Comment: comenta si te sirvió

Comment: por cierto no corrijas tu pregunta, dejala como esta y si resulta efectiva la respuesta te la colocaré para que la puntúes, así funciona la plataforma

Comment: me funciona perfecto así es como lo estoy usando` @if($product->user_id == Auth::user()->id or $product->privacidad == null and Auth::user()->uni >=100 )`

Comment: entonces si no te molesta lo agregaré como respuesta para que lo puedas calificar

Comment: claro, por supuesto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento que debería quedar así

```
@if( $user_id == auth()->user->id or $private == null and point >=100 )
```

los detalles

1. quite los parentésis de mas
2. además de eso en: `$private = null` estas asignando que la variable `$private` valga `null`, en todo caso si quieres saber si la variable `$private` es igual a `null` debes usar doble símbolo de igual `==`

Siempre debes tener presente lo siguiente:

`=` significa asignación: `$a = 5;` aquí digo la variable a es igual a 5
`==` significa comparación: `$a == $b;` aquí comparo si la variable `$a` tiene el mismo valor que `$b`

Comment: Una duda, ¿para qué sirve la @ de delante del `if`?

Comment: en la sintáxis de Blade el template engine de Laravel así se declaran los condicionales @Csc99